# How to Remove SelectedItem from a listview using ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Done my research for 3 days, nothing quite works.
Ok, so I got it to Add items to the Listview! 
How to Remove the selectedItem(s) from same instance of ObservableCollection.

What do I need in the Xaml of the Listview to get the SelectedItem(s)?

How in my RemoveModPropList, do I reference the SelectedItems and Remove them?

My XAML

```
     <Page.DataContext>
    <m:Content/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:VM_Base_ObsColl x:Key="VM_Base_ObsColl"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel
                   Background="DarkGray"
                   Height="500" Width="340"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="10,40,10,0">
        <TextBox x:Name="boxInputCategory" 
                 Header="Category"
                 Text="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay}"                  
                 Height="60" Width="250"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="boxInputTitle" 
                 Header="Title"
                 Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}"                  
                 Height="60" Width="250"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="boxInputMediaType" 
                 Header="Media Type"
                 Text="{Binding MediaType, Mode=TwoWay}"                  
                 Height="60" Width="250"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="boxInputPlayTime" 
                 Header="Play Time"
                 Text="{Binding PlayTime, Mode=TwoWay}"                      
                 Height="60" Width="250"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Lists"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="2 2"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Add" 
                      Content="Save All"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40"
                      Command="{Binding Path=Cmd_ADDModelPropsList,
                            Source={StaticResource VM_Base_ObsColl}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Remove"
                      Content="Remove"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40"                            
                      Command="{Binding Path=Cmd_RemoveModPropsList,
                        Source={StaticResource VM_Base_ObsColl}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="SQLite" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="2 2"/>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Save" 
                      Content="Save All"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      Click="AppBarBtnAddText_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel  Height="180">

            <ListView x:Name="listViewOutput"
              DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM_Base_ObsColl}}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Height="70" Width="350" Margin="1 1" Background="Gray">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"
                                       Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                       Height="30" Width="150" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                        
                                       Margin="2 2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                       Height="30" Width="150" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                        
                                       Margin="2 2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MediaType}"
                                       Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                                       Height="30" Width="150" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                        
                                       Margin="2 2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayTime}"
                                       Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
                                       Height="30" Width="150" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                        
                                       Margin="2 2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Model

```
public class Content : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Content()
    {
        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            Category = "Human Fx";
            Title = "Out the Door CheckList";
            MediaType = "Speech";
            PlayTime = "10:00 AM";               
        }         
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title + " ," + Category + " ," + MediaType + " " + PlayTime;
    }

    #region Class/Model/Record Props & Fields
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string category;
    public string Category
    {
        get => category;
        set
        {
            category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Category");
        }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => title;
        set
        {
            title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    private string mediaType;//Speech,Audio,Video
    public string MediaType
    {
        get => mediaType;
        set
        {
            mediaType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MediaType");
        }
    }

    private string playTime;
    public string PlayTime
    {
        get => playTime;
        set
        {
            playTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PlayTime");
        }
    }

    private string titleSet;
    public string TitleSet
    {
        get => titleSet;
        set
        {
            titleSet = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TitleSet");
        }
    }

    private string playSet;
    public string PlaySet
    {
        get => playSet;
        set
        {
            playSet = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PlaySet");
        }
    }

    private bool repeatsIsOn;
    public bool RepeatsIsOn
    {
        get => repeatsIsOn;
        set
        {
            repeatsIsOn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RepeatsIsOn");
        }
    }
    #endregion       
}
```

ViewModel - In the RemoveModPropsList Method, I've just no clue on how to get the selectedItem(s) from the ListView, and remove selected from the same instance of ObservableCollection.

```
    public class VM_Base_ObsColl : ObservableCollection<Content>
{
    public Cmd_ADDModelPropsList Cmd_ADDModelPropsList { get; set; }
    public Cmd_RemoveModPropsList Cmd_RemoveModPropsList { get; set; }

    public VM_Base_ObsColl()
    {
        Cmd_ADDModelPropsList = new Cmd_ADDModelPropsList(this);
        Cmd_RemoveModPropsList = new Cmd_RemoveModPropsList(this);

        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Add(new Content()
                {
                    Category = "Category " + 1+i,
                    Title = "Title " + 1+i,
                    MediaType = "Media Type " + 1+i,
                    PlayTime = "8:00 AM " + 1 + i
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void ADDModelPropsList(Content content)
    {     
        Content c = new Content();
        c.Category = content.Category;
        c.Title = content.Title;
        c.MediaType = content.MediaType;
        c.PlayTime= content.PlayTime;
        Add(c);
    }

    public void RemoveModPropsList(Content content)
    {    

        Content c = new Content();
        c.Category = content.Category;
        c.Title = content.Title;
        c.MediaType = content.MediaType;
        c.PlayTime = content.PlayTime;
        Remove(c);
    }
```

My ICommand File for Remove Selected Items

```
      public class Cmd_RemoveModPropsList : ICommand
{
    public VM_Base_ObsColl ViewModel { get; set; }

    public Cmd_RemoveModPropsList(VM_Base_ObsColl viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ViewModel.RemoveModPropsList(parameter as Content);         
    }
}
```

Comment: `ListView` needs a `SelectedItem` binding on it

Comment: `ObservableCollection.RemoveAt(ObservableCollection.IndexOf(ObservableCollectionItem));`

Comment: Thanks Matt. I made a full property in my MainViewModel with data type of Object. I called it ObservableCollectionItem and bound it to ListView's SelectedItem. the full prop is receiving the selecteditem value at run time.

Comment: `I'm not sure if the full property bound to selected item should be of type Object or `ObservableCollection<Content> SelectedItems;` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if the full property bound to Listview's SelectedItem should be of type Object or `ObservableCollection<Content> SelectedItems;` ?  I literally cannot get rid of the squiggles from your generous line of code, I put in my Delete Method.`ObservableCollection.RemoveAt(ObservableCollection.IndexOf(ObservableCollectionItem));` I believe b/c I'm not sure what to pass to the Remove method. Content content, the referencing instance of Content as 'c' in my Add method, or pass in ObservableCollectionItem property, or pass nothing in. I've tried every combo it seems. Point of clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Pass the same reference of the object you Add() to Remove()

   ```
       ObservableCollection<Class1> test = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
       Class1 obj = new Class1("Maria", 22203);
       test.Add(obj);
       test.Remove(obj); //This works
   ```
2. Use linq, if you cannot get that same reference.

   ```
       ObservableCollection<Class1> test = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();
       Class1 obj = new Class1("Maria", 22203);
       test.Add(obj);
       List<Class1> v = test.Where(x => x.Name == "Maria" && x.zip == 22203).ToList();
       foreach (Class1 c in v)
       {
           test.Remove(c); //Also works
       }
   ```

Comment: CSTruggle. Thanks! To be clear, either of the above goes in my delete method?  `public void RemoveModPropsList(Content content)` I'm not sure how to pass the bound SelectedItems value into method. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, the code above should go in your delete method. The first option is if (note the if) you get a hold of the exact same object reference that you first added. I would just try from your original code to pass the parameter object straight to remove() and see what happens.

If that does not work then you are somehow not able to get that reference. For that is the second option: you query the list for the characteristics you want, get the reference, and finally remove the object. If you have another question let me know, if not please mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are creating a new object and trying to remove this in your call to `RemoveModPropsList`. The `ObservableColltection` will try to remove this object. But it is not part of the collection. Therefore nothing will be removed.

The solution would be to get the object to remove by reference (`SelectedItem(s)` property of the `ListView`). Then you can pass the specific instances of objects to the `Remove` function of the `ObservableList`.

Comment: embarrassed to say I'm still stuck. Just trying to get it with delete a selectedItem of a Listview, that is in an Observable collection. Actually, all 3 that thank fully answered were correct. @Matt, CStruggle, and plori.

Comment: With you all's help, I've narrowed down to what all addressed. My collection that Adds bound textblock values, to listview using observable collection, I cannot get to that same collection reference in my delete method.

Comment: So in the below line, just when I thought it would work I get a null reference exception for Index out of range. I get it, the line is correct, but there is nothing in the collection of my add method's collection reference, and I can't seem to get to that collection reference in my Delete/Remove method. Any ideas?? Line that gives me Index out of range exception that I know is b/c its not referencing a collection with anything in it. This is in my  public void RemoveModPropsList(Content content) method: Contents.RemoveAt(Contents.IndexOf(observableCollectionItem));